# How can I change the channel_variable like destination_number at run time (dynamically) in Freeswitch?

Tags: freeswitch

I am looking for a solution for dynamically changing the channel_variable, destination_number without needing to reloadxml (as it might affect ongoing or incoming call). So basically, FS has to wait till I provide it with appropriate destination_number. Till now, I have been doing it XML way (editing XML files) and then reloadxml command at FS prompt. But that is not viable for my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lua(or any other freeswitch supported scripting language) script for this. Using Lua you can write custom script with very sophisticated logic.

More details:

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+API+Reference